# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'msie' of undefined or null reference

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I just tried changing my jquery ui references to the master page . I get the error above only on Internet explorer.
I dont get the error on Firefox and Chrome .

This is the jquery code where the error is thrown :

```
return a.browser.msie?(b=Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollWidth,document.body.scrollWidth),c=Math.max(document.documentElement.offsetWidth,document.body.offsetWidth),b<c?a(window).width()+"px":b+"px"):a(document).width()+"px"},resize:function(){var b=a([]);a.each(a.ui.dialog.overlay.instances,function()
```

I have the master page below :

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"
        type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ExtraHeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>


 <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerService" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ScriptMode="Auto" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" ScriptMode="Auto" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
</form>
</body>
```

Please let me know what I need to be doing ?
I tried putting the jquery references in the head section , but the jquery code within my aspx file seems to give an error saying 'dialog' object not defined or 'tooltip' object not defined. I think the jquery library is not getting loaded when I try to put the references in the head section.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[**jQuery.browser**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) has been [removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed) in jQuery 1.9 (and you use 1.10), so any attempt to process it as an object (i.e., access its `msie` property) is destined to fail. If you still want to use it, include [**jQuery migrate**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) plugin along with jQuery

Comment: Hey raina770w Thanks ! I would like to change the jquery.browser code to its updated version. Could you please let me know what I should be doing . So that my code would work without adding the new reference.Thank you !

Comment: @Courage As per the jQuery API page linked in raina77ow's answer, using the jQuery migrate plugin seems to be the only way. It says, "This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead."

Comment: I still get the error with jquery migrate loaded in the document

Answer (score 3):

I updated jquery-ui to 1.11.3 and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Add library from given link in your project.

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js

or

Register below link in your page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: or just // if you want the protocol to match your site's

Answer (score 0):

The [jquery-browser-plugin](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin) now provides the $.browser object. Including $.browser.msie